# PHP Mail. Pre-populate reply field

Tags: php, email, imap

I'm creating a standard 'reply directl to the email' PHP script using IMAP. It is only going to be used by admin users so doesn't have to be overly complicated. I have asked them to finish there messages with 'END' so I can extract everything before. Just wondered if there possibly was a header in php mail() or some other clever shit that I can do to pre-populate the reply field, with something like 'END ------ Reply above this line --------'? It doesn't have to support every email client but every little helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send the email in html format and put a link that admins can click to reply to the email, using the [mailto](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mailto) feature you can have pre-prepared content in the subject, body, to fields. An example of this:

```
<a href="mailto:someone@example.com?cc=someone_else@example.com&amp;subject=This%20is%20the%20subject&amp;body=This%20is%20the%20body">Send email</a>
```